# Laravel Vue Router Warn: Uncaught Error During Route Navigation

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-loader

My Laravel 8 project was working perfectly. I switched all my code to Laravel 9 and I get the above error? My code is exactly the same. In addition I am getting a `ChunkLoadError`? I have tried refreshing the page, clearing my views. My app.js is as follows:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from "vue";
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import HomeComponent from "./Components/Home/HomeComponent.vue";
import NavbarComponent from './Components/Navbar/NavbarComponent.vue';
const SudokuComponent = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "games/sudoku" */ "./Components/Games/Sudoku/SudokuComponent.vue");

const routes = [
    {
        name: 'home',
        path: '/',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        name: 'sudoku',
        path: '/sudoku',
        component: SudokuComponent
    }
];

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
    history: VueRouter.createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

const app = createApp({});

app.use(router);

app.component('navbar-component', NavbarComponent);

app.mount('#app');
```

I can see the sudoku.js loaded in my dev tools but I keep getting the `ChunkLoadError`?

Comment: Have you Resolve this issue?